# How many records BizTalk EDI Batching Service can handle?

Tags: biztalk, edi

I have a BizTalk application deployed to assembly X12 834 files.
it works fine to assembly a valid EDI file with about 100K records, the final file generated is about 70-80M.

But when the record count reached to about 1.2M, the performance of batching service is significantly dropped, it takes forever to complete the batch.

I tried to config the batching to release a file for about every 200K interchanges, it can generate several files but the performance also changed to unacceptable after about 500K records feeds in it.

I even tried to run the bts_CleanupMsgbox script to clear out everything in MsgBox before start the batching.

So the question is: Can BizTalk batching service handle this amount of data? The performance issue is simply cause by the design of batching service (store as XML/save state to database in every persistence points in orchestration), or I can archive to assemble file with this volume of data by some performance tuning.

Comment: It would depend to some degree on the amount of memory and CPU's your BizTalk server & database server have.  However it is well know that there are performance issues with very large message sizes in BizTalk.   There may be some tuning you can do on the host instances running the batching  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7801.biztalk-server-performance-tuning-optimization.aspx    and https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn775063(v=bts.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the built-in batching is appropriate for such amounts of data.

Is there any reason why you need such big batches? I do quite a lot of EDI, but have never encountered such a requirements.

I don't know whether this is applicable for you, but you can actually bypass the entire built-in EDI batching orchestration by mapping to an X12InterchangeXml schema. An added advantage would be that you can also control the order of the messages in the interchange as well. There are some tricks to it, but in general this might be a lot more performant.

Comment: What I am doing now is bypassing the batching service, outbound each record as a individual EDI file to a temp folder, then I have a windows services to pick up all these files then use regex to pick up the content (ST-SE) part, combining to a single EDI file.

Comment: If I understand you correctly: what you are essentially doing is processing each file at least 3 times. This is not very helpful since you say that processing is very slow due to resource limitations. Taking a different approach might save you a lot of processing power. Have you considered the X12 batch schema on this location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013 R2\XSD_Schema\EDI\X12_BatchSchema.xsd" ?

Comment: I didn't use this schema directly. But this schema is the message type that Batching service generated in my understanding. So are you suggesting to build the message with this schema with my own orchestration?

Comment: Let me explain my current approach more clearly. Now, I am using BizTalk to build EDI files for each record, this is done by a mapping from database schema to X12 schema, and an EDI send pipeline. when all these files are created, a windows service will pick up these files, wipe off ISA-IEA and GS-GE part, only keep the ST-SE part, join all these ST-SE together into one file with a new ISA-IEA and GS-GE wrapped.  Counting the ST-SE counts to make correct GE01 value. Then a valid X12 can be generated,

Answer (score 0):

First, you should double check the prevailing requirements. 1.2 million is a lot, and I've don't a lot of 834.  Not that it can't happen, but 1.2 million is large for both sides.

1.2 million *members* isn't shocking, but 1.2 million individual 834's would be very, very, very unusual.  Can you batch ~10K or so members into 1 834?  Then that's only ~100 834's.

Comment: Johns. I am not creating 1.2M 834 files, I am creating 834 files holds 1.2M members.  And since the performance issue of Batching service,  now I have to create 1.2M temp 834 files and use a windows service to combine  them.

Comment: What I mean is an 834 ST can hold multiple Members so if the Members are grouped at 10K per 834 ST, you are only BizTalk Batching ~100 834's.

Comment: i see. But this means one single 834 message holding 10k members. The message size will be huge.

Comment: But it will be smaller than 10K Individual 834 ST's with only one member.  Do you have a hard requirement to send an entire Population all at once?  If not, you may be overthinking this a bit.